# Optional chaining for interfaces that have an index signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, optional-chaining, index-signature

I defined two interfaces. The first one has an optional field, the second one has an index signature:

```
interface A {
  foo?: { bar: number };
}

interface B {
  [s: string]: { bar: number };
}
```

Why does the first interface give me a result of type `number | undefined` when I access the property using optional chaining, whereas the second one gives only type `number`?

```
const a: A = {};
const aa = a.foo?.bar;
// const aa: number | undefined

const b: B = {};
const bb = b.foo?.bar;
// const bb: number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because B is indexed by `[s: string]`, it believe that any valid string key will result in the value of `{ bar: number }` being accessed. So, with

```
const b: B = {};
const bb = b.foo?.bar;
```

it thinks that the `foo` property will always exist - it'll never fail and turn into `undefined` via optional chaining.

In contrast, with A's:

```
interface A {
  foo?: { bar: number };
}
```

Since the `foo` property is optional here, it's *not* sure to exist (to Typescript), so the `?.` may result in no property being found and `undefined` being the result.

You can make it clear that not all properties on `B` will necessarily have the `bar` object by alternating with `undefined` in the object value type:

```
interface B {
  [s: string]: { bar: number } | undefined;
}
```

resulting in `bb` being typed as `number | undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are choosing an existing property:

```
interface SomeInterface {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: string;
}
```

Then you can use the `?.[` syntax:

```
var o: SomeInterface = {
    prop1: 'test',
    prop2: 'test2'
}
console.log(o?.['prop1']);
```